# Adding new element within an element within an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm just starting to learn Javascript and I could use some help with this problem I'm having. I'm currently trying to add a p tag within a div tag that is in another div tag using DOM manipulation.

```
<div class='xxx'>
   <div> <-- I was able to create this div through DOM manipulation
      <p></p> <!-- Trying to add this tag through DOM manipulation
      <p></p> <!-- Trying to add this tag through DOM manipulation
      <p></p> <!-- Trying to add this tag through DOM manipulation
   </div>
</div>
```

I searched on Stackoverflow and wasn't able to find what I was looking for. So far this is what I've tried among a few other methods.

```
Was able to create div here:
const mainFoodDiv = document.querySelector('.food-names')
for (let i = 0; i < foodCategoryArr.length; i++) {
  const foodName = document.createElement('div')
  mainFoodDiv.append(foodName)
}

Getting an error that says foodNameP.append is not a function:
const foodNameP = document.querySelectorAll('div > div')
for (let i = 0; i < foodCategoryArr.length; i++) {
  const foodName = document.createElement('p')
  foodName.textContent = foodCategoryArr[i]
  foodNameP.append(foodName)
}
```

Can anyone guide me on where to go from here? I can only use pure javascript for this, no libraries or frameworks.

Comment: It would appear from your code that the second <div>...</div> tags are not needed.  I see no CSS that effects them and the <p> tags would act the same without them.

Comment: *I can only use pure javascript for this, no libraries or frameworks.* WHY did you tag it **jquery** then?

Answer (score 1):

`foodNameP` would be an array of `NodeList` as `querySelectorAll` returns that

if you are sure `div > div` only occur ones or is first to occur in DOM do this

```
foodNameP[0].append(foodName)
```

Or you can apply a class to it then above.